# Microphone not working with Android API level 30 but working with API level 29

Tags: android, xamarin, microphone

We have an application which uses microphone for speech to text conversion, till API level 29, it is working, however if we target it to API level 30, it does not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could it have to do with [this behavior change](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/reference/compat-framework-changes#camera_microphone_capability_change_id) when targeting Android 11?

Comment: you tried minSdkVersion 29?

Comment: Did you allow microphone permission?

Comment: You can confirm if it really is CAMERA_MICROPHONE_CAPABILITY_CHANGE_ID using Compatibility Framework Tool of Google, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758511/my-android-app-is-not-working-properly-once-i-set-targetsdk-as-api-30-how-do-i/69758512#69758512